# ionic3 - How to add backrop when fab buttion open

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using ionic3 framework. I have 4 fabs button in a page like :

```
<ion-fab top right edge>
    <button ion-fab mini><ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon></button>
    <ion-fab-list>
      <button ion-fab><ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon></button>
      <button ion-fab><ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon></button>
      <button ion-fab><ion-icon name="logo-vimeo"></ion-icon></button>
      <button ion-fab><ion-icon name="logo-googleplus"></ion-icon></button>
    </ion-fab-list>
  </ion-fab>
```

How to add backdrop when fab button is open and show one fab button visible at time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this by using css.

1. First you add the `click` handler in `fab-button`

   ```
   <button ion-fab mini (click)="hasClass = !hasClass"><ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon></button>
   ```
2. Create `hasClass` function in your .ts file

   ```
   hasClass : boolean = false
   ```
3. Use `ngClass` in to add the class based on condition

   ```
   <ion-content>
   <div *ngIf="backdrop" class="back-drop"></div>
   ...
   </ion-content>
   ```
4. Add appropriate CSS to the class in your .scss file

   ```
   .back-drop {
       position: fixed;
       top: 0;
       right: 0;
       bottom: 0;
       left: 0;
       background: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5);
   }
   ```